# how to scroll recyclerview scroll the object outside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to know is it possible to scroll recyclerview and scroll other object without using nested scroll or scrollview?

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text or other oject will list here"
    android:id="@+id/info"/>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this : Android list view inside a scroll view

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Text or other oject will list here"
             android:id="@+id/info"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> Note: set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` programmatically